# What exactly is flushed by flush/0 in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, port

I'm still an absolute newbie in Elixir:

I stumbled over the [following example](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.14.5/Port.html) in the documentation or `Port` objects:

```
port = Port.open({:spawn, "cat"}, [:binary])
send(port, {self(), {:command, "hello"}})
send(port, {self(), {:command, "world"}})
flush()
```

How does `flush()` know, what it should flush? If there would be a `port.flush()`, I would find it more understandable.

I tried to [search the Elixir docs for a documentation for the `flush` function](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/main/search.html?q=flush), but I only found `StringIO.flush`.

There does not seem to be a `Kernel.flush` either; at least it's not listed in https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.14.5/Kernel.html .

I would appreciate any pointer of where this function is defined. Also, any suggestion on how to search the online docs of Elixir better, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Great doc search resource: https://hexdocs.krister.ee/

Comment: Considering you accepted an answer that doesn't answer the actual question you asked, and not the answer that did, is this an XY question and you are actually asking how message passing works? Or how to get the output from an external command?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip : In retrospect, I see that you have a point. Actually, my goal is to learn programming in Elixir,  so I'm going through a tutorial (which I posted in my question). Since I didn't understand this example, I wanted to get it explained. I learned to my surprise, that I can't simple copy thos IEx examples into a file and run it as a program. I hadn't expected these differences, and in effect, the solution of _bortzmeyer_ is helpful, in that it can be used in programs **and** interactively.

Comment: Right but most of the time you don't need ports anyway and can use [`System.cmd`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/3).

Comment: @AdamMillerchip : Thanks, this is good to know. I stumbled over ports, because the tutorial I was reading, happened to mention ports early, and as I am a curious person, I followed the link to the explanation of ports, which gave me the example posted above. I'm now going sequentially through the [_elixir school_](https://elixirschool.com/en), and hope that this will teach me the quicker how to program in this language. I have a good background in Ruby and C, and some familiarity in Haskell and Prolog, so I hope to get fluent in Elixir quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For use under Iex, see Daniel's reply. For using in a standalone Elixir program, just read the messages from `cat` with `receive` (output from the program you spawn are simply regular Elixir messages for the Elixir process):

```
port = Port.open({:spawn, "cat"}, [:binary])
send(port, {self(), {:command, "hello"}})
send(port, {self(), {:command, "world"}})
receive do
  {_, {:data, msg}} -> IO.puts(msg)
end
send(port, {self(), :close})
```

Answer (score 3):

[flush/0](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/1.14.5/IEx.Helpers.html#flush/0) is a utility function from IEx, located in `IEx.Helpers`. You don't need to specify the module name from an `iex` session because it will be imported automatically. It does exactly what it says in the documentation:

> Clears out all messages sent to the shell's inbox and prints them out.

As for searching for documentation, this one is special this is why it was hard to find, otherwise you should have zero problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I guess those Helpers are not part of the documentation? And what do I do when I write an Elixir program (like the example in my question) and want to collect the output from a Port? According to the docs, the Port class does not have a flush function.

Comment: there is no concept of class in elixir, this is a functional language. You have functions and modules, that's it. flush/0 is a utility function provided by iex (AKA elixir repl) and used for debugging and learning. The helper functions are part of IEx package, not part of core elixir, this is why you couldn't find it in the elixir documentation.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, and also for correcting the silly typos in my post. When saying "class", I was thinking of something in the way of classes in i.e. Haskell, but I see that it is dangerous to make assumptions when learning a new language.

Comment: there are protocols in elixir, we call them callbacks, but this has nothing to do with this discussion. Port and flush() have nothing in common, flush dumps all the messages from a process, I would suggest to read about processes in elixir, as they are core concept that you need to understand.

Comment: @Daniel callbacks are for behaviours, not protocols. Also I think it's actually pretty hard to find elixir documentation in general. It's good when you find it, but you usually need to know at least which package to look in first.